# Ajax call from phonegap to login in Yii fails

Tags: ajax, cordova, yii

I'm doing my first phonegap app and I run into login problem. I have an appLogin action in the site controller and I know it reaches the controller's action and logs in - anyway the credentials get validated and login is successful. But the ajax call in app fails to get response. 
If I comment out the login part and just echo something the ajax call is succesful and receives the response. I know I'm probably missing something basic regarding authentication. What is it?

my login action in site controller:

```
public function actionAppLogin()
{

    $model=new LoginForm;

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['loginform']))
    {
        $request = $_POST['loginform'];

        $model->attributes=$request;

        if($model->validate() && $model->login()){
            //it reaches here
            echo 111;

        } else {
            echo 444;
        }

    } else {
        echo 222;
    }

}
```

My ajax login function in app:

```
BusinessBox.prototype.serLogin = function(){
var me = this;

alert("ajax login "+me.credentials.loginform.username);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: serverActions.appLogin(),
    dataType: "json",
    data: me.credentials
}).done(function( obj ) {
    alert(obj);
    if(obj) {
        me.loggedIn = true;
        alert(obj);
    } else {
        me.loggedIn = false;
        alert("not logged in");
    }
}).fail(function(err){
    alert("error log in");
});
```

}

Comment: Could you mark the part, which you comment out to receive a response?

Comment: the login part. when it is commented out it receives the response or when the login fails.

Comment: What **exactly** is "the login part", the complete action? In PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: if($model->validate() && $model->login())... this is when the logged in session starts

Comment: On which platform are you using phonegap (iOS, Android, ...)?

Answer (score 0):

Yep it's reaches that section that you marked in your comment. It's becouse you haven't send an {ajax: "login-form"} parameter in your post. 
If you alter your code, to post that param too, you can reach your ajax-specific code-segment on server-side (btw, that segment just validates the sent data, doesn't make something like authenticating workflow) .